# Login/logout emulation (Windows 7)

Tags: c#, c++, authentication, wmi, emulation

How to emulate user login/logout lock/unlock events on Windows?

I wrote some simple C# app. It starts processes (in cycle) with special credentials (user name and password), but it is not what I want.

This emulator I need for debugging my WMI consumer;

Comment: will this be helpful? http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2006/07/07/WindowsImpersonationContextMadeEasy.aspx

Comment: What does it mean to "emulate user login"?  Do you just want to call LogonUser?